# Color changing too fast for the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Color is changing too frequently on mouse move, however I want it to delayed and make it smooth but the code is not working properly.

I introduced `delay()` for this but seems not working.

Let me know what I am missing in the `concept` for using delay in the code.

jQuery Code-

```
var possible = 'ABCDEF123456';
var stringLength = 6;
$('#divcol').on('mousemove',function(){
    var randomString = Array.apply(null, new Array(stringLength)).map(function () {
    return possible[Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)];
}).join('');
    var col = "#"+randomString;
    $(this).delay(10000).css("background-color",col);
    })
```

HTML -

```
<div id="divcol" style="width:150px;height:150px;background-color:#c3c3c3;">
</div>
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/83mN7/

Something like this I am trying to achieve - http://www.aino.com/

Comment: as far as I know, `delay` online works withe `animate`. Sadly jQuery can't animate colors, only [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/animate/) can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `jQuery animation` to achieve this:

```
$(this).animate({ backgroundColor: col }, 1500);
```

Comment: Did you actually try this? That equates to `background minus color`.

Comment: Indeed, need to use backgroundColor; http://jsfiddle.net/83mN7/18/ Oh, and I changed to mouseover, mousemove too 'frequent' of an event for this I believe. (As @JanHommes pointed out, jQuery UI was included)

Comment: Should be backgroundColor

Comment: Sorry. I copy/paste the property and forgot to change it before posting. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

not the best solution, but it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/83mN7/20/

```
var possible = 'ABCDEF123456';
var stringLength = 6;
var count = 0;
$('#divcol').on('mousemove', function () {
    var randomString = Array.apply(null, new Array(stringLength)).map(function () {
        return possible[Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)];
    }).join('');
    var col = "#" + randomString;
    count = count + 1;
    if (count > 30) {
        $(this).css("background-color", col);
        count = 0;
    }

});
```

Comment: Good one +1 ..but I doubt if will be little slow due to if

Comment: yes.. and speed of change could be different on different browsers, it's not timer but counter...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried css3 transitions to accomplish this? You could check out these [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/). This however does require a jQuery fallback for older browsers that don't these support css3 effects like Internet Explorer 9, but [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/) can help you accomplish that:

```
if (!Modernizr.csstransitions) {
    $(".test").hover(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#ff0000" }, 1500)
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#0000ff" }, 1500)
    });
}
```

Another advantage of css3 transitions is that they are browser-native which means these animations can be accelerated by the GPU and this results in a smoother animation.